# MongoDB Atlas Projects/Clusters

Tags: mongodb

I have recently finished a course for the merng tech stack and now I would like to take what I have learnt and create a project of my own. During the setup for MongoDB Atlas (Free tier) on my new project, I thought of these questions:

1. Should I start a new project on my MongoDB Atlas account and create a new cluster in that project? Or just create a new cluster in the previous project? (I would assume I should start a new project as the new one has no relevance to the previous one)
2. Why would/can you have more than one cluster for one project?

I'm still fairly new to this tech stack and would like some clarity on these questions, so I apologise in advance if these come across as stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on the free tier, it's somewhat irrelevant as you can only have a single free cluster by project.

As to why you could want more than one cluster for a single project, it's mostly relevant for bigger and more complex projects. I expect a personal project to be able to scope itself to a single cluster. Where I work at, we mostly use clusters to separate domains between teams. It's also one of the easiest permission restriction to set. If you really get down to it, multiple clusters is a mean of organizing a project and you may want different configurations between your clusters, maybe you have a cluster where frequent backups is less necessary and since backups are very costly, you want to make sure you backup frequently only what needs to be.

**Update**

You might also want to explore sharding to remain on a single cluster, but that is also a costly and complex solution compared to maintaining multiple clusters since finding a relevant shard key to distribute equally the load is not a benign task. We've also moved away from separating clusters by domain, we now separate databases by domain. Databases are then distributed across clusters to balance the loads.